# Will subcaption and threeparttable live happily ever after? Trouble combining the two

Tags: tables, subfloats, subcaption, threeparttable

I'm trying to take this MWE table and put it into a `subcaption`'s **`subtable` environment**, or, alternatively, use `subcaption`'s **`subcaption` command** - see `subcaption`'s manual - to achieve the same end: to have that table twice next to each other.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}
%\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\sisetup{round-mode=places,round-precision=1, add-decimal-zero=true, add-integer-zero=true, round-integer-to-decimal}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Some long boring caption don't fall asleep 2013}

\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{@{}*{1}{l}*{2}{S[table-format=3.2]}@{}}
\toprule
& {incl.\ Ingredients A\tnote{3}} & {excl.\ Ingredients A} \\
\midrule
DDDD & 36.1 & 22.0\\
EEEE & 30.9 & 20.0\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}

\begin{tablenotes}
\item [2] Unweighted Average
\item [] Source: radiowaves from outer space 1999
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

*Inter alia* I've tried this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}
%\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\sisetup{round-mode=places,round-precision=1, add-decimal-zero=true, add-integer-zero=true, round-integer-to-decimal}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Sub_caption A 2013}

\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{@{}*{1}{l}*{2}{S[table-format=3.2]}@{}}
\toprule
& {incl.\ Ingredients A\tnote{3}} & {excl.\ Ingredients A} \\
\midrule
DDDD & 36.1 & 22.0\\
EEEE & 30.9 & 20.0\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}

\begin{tablenotes}
\item [2] Unweighted Average
\item [] Source: radiowaves from outer space 1999
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{subtable}


\begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Sub_caption B 2013}

\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{@{}*{1}{l}*{2}{S[table-format=3.2]}@{}}
\toprule
& {incl.\ Ingredients A\tnote{3}} & {excl.\ Ingredients A} \\
\midrule
DDDD & 36.1 & 22.0\\
EEEE & 30.9 & 20.0\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}

\begin{tablenotes}
\item [2] Unweighted Average
\item [] Source: radiowaves from outer space 1999
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{subtable}

\caption{Some long boring caption don't fall asleep 2013}


\end{table}

\end{document}
```

and this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}
%\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\sisetup{round-mode=places,round-precision=1, add-decimal-zero=true, add-integer-zero=true, round-integer-to-decimal}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\subcaption{Sub_caption A 2013}

\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{@{}*{1}{l}*{2}{S[table-format=3.2]}@{}}
\toprule
& {incl.\ Ingredients A\tnote{3}} & {excl.\ Ingredients A} \\
\midrule
DDDD & 36.1 & 22.0\\
EEEE & 30.9 & 20.0\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}

\begin{tablenotes}
\item [2] Unweighted Average
\item [] Source: radiowaves from outer space 1999
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{minipage}


\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\subcaption{Sub_caption B 2013}

\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{@{}*{1}{l}*{2}{S[table-format=3.2]}@{}}
\toprule
& {incl.\ Ingredients A\tnote{3}} & {excl.\ Ingredients A} \\
\midrule
DDDD & 36.1 & 22.0\\
EEEE & 30.9 & 20.0\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}

\begin{tablenotes}
\item [2] Unweighted Average
\item [] Source: radiowaves from outer space 1999
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{minipage}

\caption{Some long boring caption don't fall asleep 2013}


\end{table}

\end{document}
```

which both return the `Package tabulary Warning: No suitable columns! on input line 31.` error message. I could post additional failed attempts, but don't think that'd be helpful, would it?

Is there same mistake, or some incompatibility?

Note that I'd like to at least be able to apply the threeparttable with footnotes to all three tables: both the two subtables individually, as well as the "mother table" (whether in the end I'd combine the footnotes (or use any footnotes at all) is another matter...).

Futher, is `subcaption` capable of doing the list list-of-tables thing also of the subtables layed out neatly as in this `subfig` example [here](http://texblog.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/subfig-sample-code-output.pdf) from [here](http://texblog.org/tag/subtable/)?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

`tabulary` works by changing the width of `L`, `C`, `R` or `J` columns to achieve the requested total width. You have not supplied any such columns so it can do nothing except complain:

```
Package tabulary Warning: No suitable columns!
```

This is unrelated to any table/subtable environment in which the construct is used.

Then you get `$` errors because there is a `_` in the caption and the tables come one above the other as they are in separate paragraphs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}
%\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\sisetup{round-mode=places,round-precision=1, add-decimal-zero=true, add-integer-zero=true, round-integer-to-decimal}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Sub\_caption A 2013}

\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{@{}*{1}{L}*{2}{c}@{}}
\toprule
%& {incl.\ Ingredients A\tnote{3}} & {excl.\ Ingredients A} \\
\midrule
DDDD & 36.1 & 22.0\\
EEEE & 30.9 & 20.0\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}

\begin{tablenotes}
\item [2] Unweighted Average
\item [] Source: radiowaves from outer space 1999
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{subtable}%
\begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Sub\_caption B 2013}


\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{@{}*{1}{L}*{2}{S[table-format=3.2]}@{}}
\toprule
& {incl.\ Ingredients A\tnote{3}} & {excl.\ Ingredients A} \\
\midrule
DDDD & 36.1 & 22.0\\
EEEE & 30.9 & 20.0\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}

\begin{tablenotes}
\item [2] Unweighted Average
\item [] Source: radiowaves from outer space 1999
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{subtable}

\caption{Some long boring caption don't fall asleep 2013}


\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Somehow `l` lingered in my MWE; but that doesn't seem to be causing the error message; replacing it by `L` doesn't do the trick. Further, the first MWE above (with no sub-tables) just works. So even if the error message of MWE 2 and 3 *seems to* complain via/about `tabulary` I don't attribute the problem (directly) to `tabulary`.

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty see code in answer which produces no error messages

Comment: don't know why, but that code produces an error message (albeit a different one) for me: `Package caption Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \caption (caption) in the last figure or table. See the caption package documentation for explanation.` I'm using `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)` in `Gummi`.

Comment: in_ exactly_ the code I posted? That's odd: add \listfiles to the preamble and post your log

Comment: pasted the log here http://paste.ubuntu.com/5718167/

Comment: You have an older version of expl3, I have `Package: expl3 2013/03/14 v4469 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper` (and l3names similarly) which means I would guess you are hitting a weird siunitx incompatibility it's only siunitx that triggers l3 code in your MWE I think.

Comment: tried it here https://www.writelatex.com/138192bfbdjs too; this also produces an (unspecified) error.

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty in one of the tables I'd removed S replacing by c while I was testing, do the same with the other then remove siunitx (you could remove utf8 inputec as well that would remove an awful lot of code and help narrow down where the different behaviour is

Comment: That could well be; other than installing experimental beta stuff (not in the mood at this stage in writing ;) can you think of a good workaround solution? I'd like to keep keeps siunitx, threeparttable and subcaption cuz the two small tables I produced with them just look so neat... I'd rather use two small separate tables (this is for a thesis, not a publication, after all) than do without these packages...

Comment: It seems that `threeparttable` is incrementing main the `table` counter, even in `subtable` environments. Therefore the Table is titled `Table 3` and not `Table 1` as it should be. Futhermore both sub-tables are titled `(a)`. I will take a look at this within the next days...

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/tickets/8/

Comment: ...fixed with caption.sty v3.3-86

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I finally got it working with `subfig` instead of `subcaption`.

Apparently, I'd need to install bleeding-edge LaTeX Kernel (thanks David Carlisle, Joseph Wright and Axel Sommerfeldt for noticing and looking into this !)

But after this whole shlep, I remembered the ideas expressed in the `booktabs` manual (and other common table-style-guides) and found a solution which *avoids* subfigs & subtables altogether: I "figured" that I'd end up with more lines than text (so-to-speak), and that there's a different way of constructing the table which will reduce the number of lines to the recommended three plus x (`\toprule \middlerule \bottomrule` and `\cmidrule`) which just looks SOOO much better.

Bottom line: in TeX there surely will be a way of cookin' up something fancily complicated (and potentially ugly): but simplicity often begets beauty.