# How to properly use subcaption with threeparttable

Tags: subfloats, subcaption, threeparttable, tablenotes

I'm trying to use the `subcaption` package inside the `threeparttable` environment, but can't get it work. I know there could be [some issues](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109339/will-subcaption-and-threeparttable-live-happily-ever-after-trouble-combining-th) with the two but I simply can't abandon the TPTT.

Apparently I get no error message but the sub-captions don't show up.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{geometry,array,graphicx,float,caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\caption{Samples picture} \label{fig:picture_temp}
    \centering
\begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Before}
        \label{fig:1a}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-c}
        \caption{After}
        \label{fig:1b}
    \end{subfigure}    
    \begin{tablenotes}
     \item Diference in samples over the range of temperatures.
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Sorry for the meme, I couldn't resist.

[image: two images side by side with no subcaption]

Comment: https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues/41

Comment: Fixed with caption v3.4f. If someone had noticed me about this bug (which I found here by pure accident), it would have been fixed three years ago. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `threeparttable` the meaning of `\@caption` is changed. You want that inside of `subfigure` the meaning is as established by `caption`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{geometry,array,graphicx,caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{subfigure}{\let\@caption\caption@original@caption}
\AtBeginDocument{\let\caption@original@caption\@caption}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\caption{Samples picture} \label{fig:picture_temp}
    \centering
\begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Before}
        \label{fig:1a}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-c}
        \caption{After}
        \label{fig:1b}
    \end{subfigure}    
    \begin{tablenotes}
     \item Difference in samples over the range of temperatures.
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The original meaning (as further modified by `memoir`) has to be saved at begin document. With `\AtBeginDocument` I restore that meaning, but only inside `subfigure`. You may need the same for tables.

[image]

Comment: 1. `\caption@caption` is already defined (and used) by the `caption` package, so better use `\@caption@original` or something like this. 2. This patch does not fix `\subcaption` or `\subcaptionbox` inside `threeparttable`. 3. I just fixed this bug in caption v3.4f. 4. egreg, please inform me about such bugs so I get at least the chance of fixing it ;) (E-mail with subject "FYI" and SX link as body is sufficient.) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I replaced the `subcaption` with the `subfig` package and used the `\subfloat` command, now it works like a charm with `\tnotes` in the (sub)caption.

Another option, without using threeparttable, can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240767/spacing-of-notes-below-a-figure) using a simple `\footnotesize` inside figure environment.

[image: Two subfloats with \tnote in caption]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{geometry,array,graphicx,float,caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{position=bottom}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\caption{Samples picture} \label{fig:picture_temp}
    \centering
\begin{threeparttable}
        \subfloat[Before]{
        \includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-b}
        \label{fig:1a} 
        }
    ~
        \subfloat[After \tnote{a}]{
        \includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-c}
        \label{fig:1b}
        }    
    \begin{tablenotes}
     \item Diference in samples over the range of temperatures.
     \item[a] Calculated.
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should note that subfig may have problems with hyperref (that's why the general suggestion is to use subcaption instead in the first place).